# PHP display in minute only

Tags: php

Sorry for my bad english, im trying to convert duration from given date time range in minute only. There something weird when display only %I. My final out put using variable $durationDisplayMin. How how convert in minute only?

```
$startDate = "2018-01-20 15:10:10";
$end_datetime = "2018-07-29 11:11:05";
$start_datetime = new DateTime($startDate);
$end_datetime = new DateTime($endDate);
$diffr = $start_datetime->diff($end_datetime);
$durationDisplayMin = $diffr->format("%I");
```

Comment: Second line in incorrect. You should use `$endDate` instead of `$end_datetime`

Comment: haha my mistake

Comment: `$durationDisplayMin = (strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / 60;` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2a03273ecb77b3648415dae7a7717d3842057d6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found the answer:

```
$durationInMin = 0;
$start_datetime = new DateTime("2018-01-20 15:10:10");
$end_datetime = new DateTime("2018-07-29 11:11:05");
$Date1 = strtotime($start_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$Date2 = strtotime($end_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$durationInMin += round(abs($Date1 - $Date2)/ 60,2);
```